# Превратить таблицу тарифных зон в условия на JS

Tags: javascript

Подскажите как лучше и проще всего превратить таблицу тарифных зон "Новой почты" по ссылке http://novaposhta.ua/uploads/misc/doc/taryfni_zony.pdf в условия на чистом Джаваскрипте?

Для тех кто не в курсе: в левой вертикальной колонке берется область, с которой один человек отправляет груз, а в правой горизональной полосе берется область, где другой человек принимает отправленный груз. На пересечении областей получается номер тарифной зоны (чем дальше одна область от другой, тем больше номер).

Области Украины предварительно перевел в числа т.е. Киевская область например это 9-ка (9-я по порядку в таблице), Одесская соответственно 14, Днепровская 3, Львовская 12 и т.д.

Первое что приходит в голову это:

```
if(numberOfSenderRegion == 9 && numberOfReceiverRegion == 3 || numberOfSenderRegion == 3 && numberOfReceiverRegion == 9 || numberOfSenderRegion == 9 && numberOfSenderRegion == 14 || numberOfReceiverRegion == 14 && numberOfReceiverRegion == 9 || numberOfSenderRegion == 9 && numberOfSenderRegion == 12 || numberOfReceiverRegion == 12 && numberOfReceiverRegion == 9) {
    var numberOfZone = 4;
}
```

и так получается кто знает сколько подобных условий нужно прописать лишь для 4-й зоны

Есть ли способ попроще?

ps. зону 0 (отправка в пределах одной области) не считаем, там одного условия достаточно:

```
if(numberOfSenderRegion == numberOfReceiverRegion) {
    var numberOfZone = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно, есть простой вариант, правда Вам придется вначале немного попотеть. Нужно сделать себе хеш следующего вида

```
{"1-0": 4, "2-0": 4, "2-1": 5, .... }
```

Обяснения хеша. Ключем являются номера областей через минус (можно конечно и по две буквы взять, тогда ключ будет выглядеть где то так "od-ky"). Значение - это просто значение. Так как похоже, что таблица симметрична, то можно сохранить только половину значений.

Теперь, как пользоваться. После того, как получены две области, переводим их в цифровое значение или буквенное (скорее всего это за Вас сделать html верства сама:) ). Проверяем, что это не одна и та же область и меняем ключи местами, если нужно (я в своем примере сохранил больший ключ первым, но это условность). Дальше, имея два кода области, формируем ключи и ищем в таблице.

Этот подход достаточно хорош:
- поиск быстр, где то за логарифм (точно быстрее, чем серия if/switch)
- легко модифицировать произвольные изменения. Нужно только найти в списке:)
- таблицу легко хранить в отдельном файле.

Недостатки:
- таблицу нужно сгенерировать. Но это делается один раз.
- нужно решить, что важно - память или понятные ключи.

В таблице 24 области. 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + 23 = 23 * 12 = 276 ключей. Даже если хранить по три буквы на имя области, то это меньше 4кб текста. Так что все ок.

Как бы я генерировал таблицу. Я бы аккуратно перенес ее в excel и потом сохранил в csv (или другой удобный формат). А потом простым скриптом на любимом для этого дела языке (у меня это перл:) ) написал бы генератор готового js. Хотя я думаю, есть специалисты, которые это сделают на vbscript прямо в экселе.

Comment: Спасибо, но к сожалению не настолько силен в JS чтобы понять как получить такой хеш. Могли бы вы хотя бы на примере одной парочки областей проиллюстрировать весь код?

Comment: А я собственно что в ответе что привел?  0 - это Винница, 1 - Волынь, 2 - Днепро. Или Вы хотите готовый код и всю таблицу сразу?

Comment: Нет, вы не совсем поняли. Как получить такой хеш или как с ним работать? (не знаю как точно выразится).